# Join items of a list with '+' sign in a string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I would like my output to be :

```
Enter a number : n
List from zero to your number is : [0,1,2,3, ... , n]
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ... + n = sum(list)
```

Yet my actual output is :

```
Enter a number : 5
List from zero to your number is :  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[+0+,+ +1+,+ +2+,+ +3+,+ +4+,+ +5+] =  15
```

I'm using `join` as it's the only type I know.

Why are the plus signs printed around the items and why are they surrounding blank spaces?

How should I print the `list`'s values into a string for the user to read ?

Thank you. Here's my code :

```
##Begin n_nx1 application
n_put = int(input("Choose a number : "))

n_nx1lst = list()
def n_nx1fct():
    for i in range(0,n_put+1):
        n_nx1lst.append(i)
    return n_nx1lst

print ("List is : ", n_nx1fct())
print ('+'.join(str(n_nx1lst)) + " = ", sum(n_nx1lst))
```

Comment: When you write `str(n_nx1lst)`, you're getting a string representation of your list, so the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` literally becomes the string `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"`

Comment: …actually `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"` and then the join will take the string as a list of characters, inserting a `+` in between each. Thus the `[+1+ +,+ +2+,+ +3+,+ +4+]`

Comment: I'd just like to add now that the right answer has been posted that your variable names are awful.. Very confusing and hard to read.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to write a function to construct your list. Just do `n_nx1lst = list(range(n_put+1))`. But if you _really_ want to do this with a function it should take the number as an argument, and it should construct   a new list in the function and return it.

Comment: Greg + @spectras : Thank you. You're right. I was turning everything of that list into a string. Jim explained to me that I should've iterated through each item.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld. Sorry to hear that : It's actually n_nx1 list (n_nx1lst) and n_nx1 function (n_nx1fct). I can't change them now that they're mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring I read a cool answer by mrdomoboto where he used this method (That I didn't know). I'm still learning Python so anything I use, it will be for the sake of my own grasp. Too early for code optimization [ : I'll make another Python script using the range function after I finished this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change each individual `int` element in the `list` to a `str` inside the `.join` call instead by using a `generator expression`:

```
print("+".join(str(i) for i in n_nx1lst) + " = ", sum(n_nx1lst))
```

In the first case, you're calling `str` on the whole `list` and not on individual elements in that `list`. As a result, it *joins each character in the representation of the list*, which looks like this:

```
'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'
```

with the `+` sign yielding the result you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you. That did the job and also got the difference between changing a whole int list into a str and changing each str into an int. You rule [ :

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `str` on your list. That returns the str representation of your list and the output of that is joined with `'+'`.

You can instead use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert each item in your list to `str`, then `join`:

```
print('+'.join(map(str, n_nx1lst)) + " = ", sum(n_nx1lst))
```

You can also use the new style formatting to have a more readable output:

```
result = '+'.join(map(str, n_nx1lst))
print("{} = {}".format(result, sum(n_nx1lst)))
```

Comment: he should've had, I'll +1 this since it offers a nice alt.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe the down-voter didn't like you suggesting `map` to a newbie who doesn't even know how to write a simple function properly.

Comment: @PM2Ring You do have a point. But map is probably as easy to grab as a comprehension. That is subjective though.

Comment: Thank you. I will check map functions.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is concatenate a **string** element with ' + ' for *each* element in your list. All you need from there is to have some string formatting.

```
def sum_of_input():
    n = int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))  # Get our raw_input -> int
    l = range(n + 1)  # Create our list of range [ x≥0 | x≤10 ]
    print("List from zero to your number: {}".format(l))
    print(' + '.join(str(i) for i in l) + ' = {}'.format(sum(l)))
```

**Sample output:**

```
>>> sum_of_input()
Enter a number : 10
List from zero to your number: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
```

**How does it work?**

We use what's called a [list comprehension (5.1.3)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (*generator in this specific usage*) to iterate over our list of `int` elements creating a `list` of `string` elements. *Now* we can use the `string` method `join()` to create our desired format.

```
>>> [str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
>>> ' + '.join(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
'1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10'
```

Comment: Your code is brilliant. I really wish I could accept two answers. You definetly taught a new thing to test around.

Answer (score 0):

Using `f-string` :

```
n_put = range(int(input("Choose a number : ")))

res = sum(n_put)

print ("List is : ", [*n_put])

print(*n_put, sep="+", end = f" = {res}")
```

gives

```
Choose a number : 5
List is :  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
0+1+2+3+4 = 10
```