# .join() elements of a user generated list using range in Python

Tags: python, list, range

In my program user enters a number (input_n) that will go through :
0+1+2+ ... + n = n*(n+1)/2 axiom.

My desired output for an input_n <= 10 (in this case : 5)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 =  15
5*(5+1)/2 =  15
```

My desired output for an input_n > 10 (in this case : 999)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 995 , 996, 997, 998, 999]
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + 995 + 996 + 997 + 998 + 999  =  499500
999*(999+1)/2 =  499500
```

I thought I could use two range functions with a " + ... + " string between them in a print statement.
But what I'm typing must be nonsensical since I get a syntax error :

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

What does that error mean ? I get that the expression in question must be parenthesized. I tried to correct the error with my beginner's logic but my attempts failed.

Here's my code :

```
input_n = int(input("Choisissez un nombre : "))

input_list = list()
for i in range(0,input_n+1):
    input_list.append(i)

if input_n <= 10:
    print ("+".join(str(i) for i in input_list) + " = ", sum(input_list))
    print (str(input_n)+'*'+'('+str(input_n)+'+1)/2 = ', int(input_n*(input_n+1)/2))
elif input_n > 10:
    print("+".join(str(i) for i in range(5)) + " + ... +" + "+".join(str(i) for i in range(input_n-5,input_n+1), sum(input_list)))
    print (str(input_n)+'*'+'('+str(input_n)+'+1)/2 = ', int(input_n*(input_n+1)/2))
```

---

For noobs, like me :
I already got answers for previous encountered problems in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595362/join-items-of-a-list-with-sign-in-a-string), you should definetly check the answers given.

Comment: Can you start with an empty string, concatenate each iteration and then print the final result?

Comment: I don't understand why you are writing `print('+'.join(...) + ' = ', sum(...))` instead of `print('+'.join(...), '=', sum(...))`. Either you first concatenate the string and pass the final result to `print` or you make use of `print`'s multiple arguments. Mixing the two doesn't really make sense, especially in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely keep that in mind. All formatting, either proper or circus-like is equally new to me. I'm willing to get some order into my coding once I get a better hold of the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the bracket of the `join` built-in method, so I guess this is what you want:

```
>>> input_list = list(range(21))
>>> 
>>> input_n = 20
>>> print("+".join(str(i) for i in range(5)) + " + ... +" + "+".join(str(i) for i in range(input_n-5,input_n+1)) + ' = ', sum(input_list))
0+1+2+3+4 + ... +15+16+17+18+19+20 =  210
```

Comment: Thank you, you brought me back from a crazy direction I was headed in. I still spent a good ten minutes to figure out that I had the correct number of parentheses but one was misplaced in a comical manner. I'm grateful I didn't get downvoted, actually.

Comment: @randomhopeful .. sure ;)

Answer (score 2):

The traceback is showing you this:

> ```
> ....join(str(i) for i in range(input_n-5,input_n+1), sum(input_list)))
> ```

What is written here makes no sense. Revise it until it does.

Comment: I see; in this case : sum(input_list) must have been interpreted as a second range. I'll try adding a string and use the the {} .format function

Comment: Not as a second range, but as either the second element of a tuple (with the result of `range()` as the first) *or* as the second argument to `join()`. The lexer has decided that ambiguous cases like this are an error.

Comment: Thank you. The other answer got what I did wrong through my head. Yours explained the gibberish the lexer had to put up with.